# Magento 2 : How to focus google map on Tokyo and Yokohama by default

Tags: magento2, jquery, google-map

I want focus google map on Tokyo and Yokohama by default.

My map like this

[image]

I want my map like this by default

[image]

Please help me ! Thanks all

Comment: Which extension you are using for loading map? or using any script, please share more details.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you must have embedded google maps (Using a extension or manually added it)

You can pass the lat and long by adding `&ll=LAT, LONG` , You just have to look for that file where google maps is embedded as iframe

ex:

> &ll=40.7127, -74.0059

Just add it to the end of the link in src

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zkqAm4_X6ia8.kj6iIDUiDRdc&hl=es&ll=40.7127, -74.0059" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

You can probably can focus on Kwasaki and set an appropriate zoom to show both the cities that you want to show 
[More URL Params that you can use](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide)